# Concatenate multiple SQL scripts using CodeSmith template

Tags: concatenation, sql-scripts, codesmith

I'm trying to create simple tool for concatenating SQL scripts using CodeSmith.

I have template which is generally just:

- header (check whether tables exists, begin transaction)
- body (concatenated scripts should be placed here)
- footer (commit or rollback transaction)

Scripts are stored in separate .sql files. I need to pick these files through CodeSmith Explorer during template generation, but I don't know which `UITypeEditor` to choose.

I've tried FileNameEditor, but it allows to choose only one file.

Is there any existing `UITypeEditor` for this purpose? Or do I need to create such by myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to pick a fie then the [FileNameEditor](https://codesmith.atlassian.net/wiki/display/Generator/Adding+Designer+Support) is your best choice. If you wish to choose multiple files I'd create my [own](https://codesmith.atlassian.net/wiki/display/Generator/Building+a+custom+UITypeEditor). If you have to parse the sql files then I'd recommend just selecting a base folder using a [UITypeEditor](http://forums.asp.net/post/1815965.aspx) and then using DirectoryInfo to get a list of files matching a pattern in that directory.

If you are looking to concat the output of various templates this can be done via a [Generator Project File (See project options -> Single File)](https://codesmith.atlassian.net/wiki/display/Generator/Project+Options) out of the box or you could update your master template to accomplish this.